# Select from other table only if all columns are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL to get the address and other information for the employee.

```
SELECT   
  emp_id,  
  emp_name,
  @addr1 = ISNULL(ma.addr1, ba.addr1),  
  @addr2 = ISNULL(ma.addr2, ba.addr2),  
  @addr3 = ISNULL(ISNULL(ma.addr3, ba.addr3),''),  
  @addr4 = ISNULL(ISNULL(ma.addr4, ba.addr4),''),  
  @addr5 = ISNULL(ISNULL(ma.addr5, ba.addr5),''),  
  @postCode = ISNULL(ma.postcode, ba.postcode)  
 FROM dbo.employee e
 INNER JOIN MainAddress ma ON ma.AddressId=e.AddressId
 INNER JOIN SecondaryAddress ba ON ba.AddressId=e.AddressId
```

The problem is when Addr1 or other field in main address is NULL, it takes the Addr3 or other in secondary address and shows the mixed of both address. Which is totally invalid.

**How can I get the secondary address when all the fields in the primary address is NULL(not available)?**

**Note:** The user can update both tables or only one table.

Answer (score 3):

If "not being available" means that there is no record in the `MainAddress` table, then the `ma.AddressId` is null, and thus, you can use this condition for each field:

```
  CASE WHEN ma.AddressId IS NULL THEN ba.addr1 ELSE ma.addr1 END,
```

If you really have to check that all the fields are null, you have to change the CASE condition like this:

```
  CASE WHEN 
    ma.addres1 IS NULL AND ma.addres2 IS NULL ...
  THEN ba.addr1 ELSE ma.addr1 END,
```

*Note: if there are two possible cases, 1, that there is  no row at all, and 2, that the row exists, but the values are all null, you need to check it like this:*

```
ma.AddresId IS NULL OR (ma.addres1 IS NULL AND ma.addres2 IS NULL AND ...)
```

As said in the comment, I forgot to tell that you must use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. If not, if there is no record for an employee in any of the adress tables, the employee will not be returned by the query.

By the way, it would be much easier if you had a single address table, with a discriminator column which specifies the kind of address: main or secondary. If you did so, you would simply have to select a `LEFT JOIN` from employee table and a query that get the `TOP 1` from the address table. This will make things easier for your application developer for many other cases, for example for looking an addressthat you don't know if it's the main or not.

**UPDATE: Using a CTE**

As for the OP comment, it's necessary to use the long expression. To make it more clear and maintainable, a CTE can be used like this:

```
WITH ea AS -- the CTE, ea includes "employee + MainAdressExists column"
(
SELECT 
    *, -- select the required columns
    -- plus an extra calculated column
    CASE WHEN 
       ma.address1 IS NOT NULL 
       OR ma.address2 IS NOT NULL
       -- add here all the column checks
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MainAddressExists 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN MainAddres ma ON ma.IdAddress = e.IdAdress
)
SELECT
  -- choose the needed fields from ea
  CASE WHEN P.MainAddressExists = 1 THEN ma.addres1 ELSE ba.address1 END 
  AS address1,
  -- choose all the other address fields
FROM ea
LEFT JOIN MainAddress ma ON ma.AddressId=e.AddressId
LEFT JOIN SecondaryAddress ba ON ba.AddressId=e.AddressId
```

Comment: If ma.IdAddress IS NULL then you get no results. Change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: No the records will be available in both the tables sometimes. That is the problem

Comment: @Billa No, that's not a problem. It has the solution I've given you. I've improved my answer showing you how to make it a bit shorter and cleare using a CTE.

Comment: @JotaBe just relax, I had started typing the query already and felt like a waste not posting the full thing. Your CTE is a much nicer solution so I deleted my post and upvoted your ;) just remember not everybody is out to get you.

Comment: @Tristan. I'm sorry, I saw your answer rigth now, so I thought you had just written it, and I simply didn't understand why you had taken the time to write the whole thing when the solution was already explained, and I was just trying to call your attention. I didn't mean to be rude. That's why my comment ended with a ;) I insist, I'm sorry.

Comment: `CASE 
 WHEN ma.addr1 IS NULL AND ma.ADDR2 IS NULL AND ma.addr3 IS NULL AND ma.addr4 IS NULL 
 THEN 
    @addr1 = ISNULL(ba.addr1,''),  
    @addr2 = ISNULL(ba.addr2,''),  
    @addr3 = ISNULL(ba.addr3,''),  
    @addr4 = ISNULL(ba.addr4,''),  
    @addr5 = ISNULL(ba.addr5,''),  
 ELSE
       @addr1 =ISNULL(ma.addr1,''),  
    @addr2 = ISNULL(ma.addr2,''),  
    @addr3 = ISNULL(ma.addr3,''),  
    @addr4 = ISNULL(ma.addr4,''),  
    @addr5 = ISNULL(ma.addr5,''),  
    END` Showing syntax error